Iteration Limit for expression involving Gamma functions
I am using an old version (13.0.0 Windows) so this might be a bug that has already been fixed, unfortunately I don't have access to a more recent version.
On a fresh kernel,

(Plain text: (Gamma[-(3/8)]^2 Gamma[1/8] ^2 Sqrt[-((2 Gamma[-(3/4)] Gamma[-(1/8)])/(Gamma[-(5/8)] Gamma[3/4]))])/ (Gamma[-(1/8)]^2) )
What is going on? Can I fix this somehow?

Same behavior in 14.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 1, 2024). Same behavior when I first do $IterationLimit=65536; Numerator evaluates without complaint, adding the denominator seems to trigger this. Simplify[numerator] doesn't help. Removing the Sqrt term  evaluates without complaint

Reported as a bug.

Thanks yall${}{}$

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

expr1 = HoldForm[(Gamma[-(3/8)]^2 Gamma[
        1/8]^2 Sqrt[-((2 Gamma[-(3/4)] Gamma[-(1/8)])/(Gamma[-(5/8)] Gamma[
             3/4]))])/Gamma[-(1/8)]^2];

expr1 // ReleaseHold

(* $IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded.

TerminatedEvaluation["IterationLimit"] *)

It can however be evaluated numerically.
expr1N = expr1 // N // ReleaseHold

(* 46.5464 *)

Presumably there is a problem with the exact negative arguments to Gamma. However, since
Gamma[x] == Gamma[x + 1]/x // FullSimplify

(* True *)

Increment each of the Gamma's negative arguments
expr2 = (expr1 /. Gamma[x_?Negative] :> Gamma[x + 1]/x) // ReleaseHold // 
  FullSimplify

(* (8 π Gamma[1/4]^(5/2) Sqrt[5/(3 Gamma[3/8] Gamma[3/4])])/(9 Gamma[7/8]^(
 3/2)) *)

expr1N == expr2

(* True *)


After having looked in the documentation, this can be fixed in 14.1 on Windows 10  as follows.
a = Block[{$IterationLimit = Infinity}, 
FullSimplify[(Gamma[-(3/8)]^2 Gamma[
   1/8]^2 Sqrt[-((2 Gamma[-(3/4)] Gamma[-(1/8)])/(Gamma[-(5/
           8)] Gamma[3/4]))])]]


-4 2^(3/4) Gamma[-(3/4)]^3 Sqrt[(3 \[Pi] Gamma[-(1/8)])/Gamma[-(5/8)]]

a/Gamma[-(1/8)]^2


-((4 2^(3/4) Gamma[-(3/4)]^3 Sqrt[(3 \[Pi] Gamma[-(1/8)])/ Gamma[-(5/8)]])/Gamma[-(1/8)]^2)

Addition. On a fresh kernel in 14.1
Block[{$IterationLimit = Infinity}, 
FullSimplify[(Gamma[-(3/8)]^2 Gamma[
    1/8]^2 Sqrt[-((2 Gamma[-(3/4)] Gamma[-(1/8)])/(Gamma[-(5/
            8)] Gamma[3/4]))])]/Gamma[-(1/8)]^2] // Timing


{0.296875, -(( 4 2^(3/4) Gamma[-(3/4)]^3 Sqrt[(3 \[Pi] Gamma[-(1/8)])/ Gamma[-(5/8)]])/Gamma[-(1/8)]^2)}

